# How can I solve this proof using induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I currently have an induction proof that I have a little trouble solving:

let $x \in R $ be fixed. Use induction to prove that any $n \in N$,
$$(1+2x)^n = 2^0 \binom{n}{0} x^0 + 2^1\binom{n}{1}x^1 + \dotsb + 2^n\binom{n}{n}x^n = \sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^i\binom{n}{i}x^i$$

Here is what I have so far, I'm not too sure if this is correct but I can't seem to simplify the last step so my guess is that I did something wrong along the way but I'm not too sure what I did wrong.

$\mathtt{Basecase: } \text{for n=1, } (1+2x)^1 = 2^0\binom{1}{0}x^0 + 2^1\binom{1}{1}x^1 = 1+2x$
$\mathtt{Induction} \text{ }\mathtt{ Hyp: } \text{for some n>1,} (1+2x)^{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$
$\mathtt{Induction} \text{ } \mathtt{Step: }$ $$(1+2x)^{n+1} = 2^0\binom{n}{0}x^0+\dotsb+ 2^n\binom{n}{n}x^n + 2^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$$
$$ (1+2x)^{n+1} = (1+2x)^n + 2^{n+1}(1)x^{n+1}$$

I'm not sure where to from here. I can't seem to find any way for the right side to be equal to the left side. Is there a common factor that I'm not seeing here? I apologize for my mis-alligned equal signs, I'm fairly new to using MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

Induction hypothesis should be:

$$(1+2x)^n = 2^0 \binom{n}{0} x^0 + 2^1\binom{n}{1}x^1 + \dotsb + 2^n\binom{n}{n}x^n = \sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^i\binom{n}{i}x^i$$

Your induction hypothesis and induction step look exactly the same.

And the proof can be found all over the net and in any algebra book, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643530/proof-for-binomial-theorem)

Your special case has $a=1$ and $b=2x$