# Is there a theorem you can use to state that if two polynomials are equal, then their homogenous parts are equal?

Tags: polynomials

Consider for example, polynomials of this form:

$$ a_o + (a_{1} x^1 + b_{1} y^1) + (a_2 x^2 + b_{11} x^1 y^1 + b_{2} y^2)... = a_o^{'} + (a_{1}^{'} x^1 + b_{1}^{'} y^1) + (a_2^{'} x^2 + b_{11}^{'} x^1 y^1 + b_{2}^{'} y^2)..$$

Then, could we say that:

$$ a_o = a_o^{'}$$
$$ a_1 x^1 + b_1 y^1 = a_1^{'} x^1 + b_1^{'} y^1$$

And so on.

Further, how would we justify such an idea?

Comment: For *polynomials* this follows basically from the definition (i.e. two polynomials are equal if their coefficients are equal), however in the case of *polynomial functions* you can argue via derivatives (Assuming you work over $\Bbb R$, otherwise the statement might be wrong anyway)

Comment: For example $a_1$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ of the left side at $(0,0)$ and similar for the other side and the other coefficients.

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with the coefficent equal thing in case of one variable polynomial but I'm was having a hard time justifying it in case for two variable ones.